# datagrid drag and drop styling

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

When I enter with a dragged item into datagrid, a bold line appears over the active row of the datagrid (which is fine to show the active row), but the problem is that even after I drop the item into datagrid, that line remains there. It goes only if I enter with a new item (in which case a new line comes to the respective row again).

I am using custom handler for dragdrop event for this datagrid.

Could anyone let me know how to get rid of this line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.flexer.info/2008/02/08/how-to-remove-the-black-line-from-a-tree-control-drag-and-drop-enabled/:

> To resolve a “sticky” black line, just
>   call
>   `dataGridId.hideDropFeedback(event);` at
>   the end of your drop handler function.

Comment: You have just taken me out of a misery. This was one of the most helpful answers I got in this forum, I could not imagine wasting hours to dig out this little information from net. Thanks again.